# How to match values in two columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns with IDs and I want to sort those two columns so the matching IDs appear next to each other, and if an ID exists only in one columns, then it leaves a blank cell in the corresponding column.

Looking for a formula or simple way to do this.

I tried to use a couple formulas but they didn't work.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this way the community can have better understanding about your question and desired results.

Comment: It is unclear what your requirement actually is (thinking about duplicates and unique values in one or both columns). Please share a screenshot of your data and the expected result. Also, share some of the formulas you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest and efficient procedure is to use index match function.following step with formula attached below

1. Use index match formula at Column C that will use range of Column B by matching for matching column A Cell value and paste the result value of Col C if value available at Col B
2. Select Column C Press `Ctrl + C` , `Ctrl + Alt + V` and select Col B
3. Delete Column B .

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1, B:B, 0)), INDEX(B:B, MATCH(A1, B:B, 0)), "")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
=HSTACK(  XLOOKUP(  SORT(UNIQUE(VSTACK(A1:A8,B1:B8))),  A1:A8,A1:A8,""  ),  XLOOKUP(  SORT(UNIQUE(VSTACK(A1:A8,B1:B8))),  B1:B8,B1:B8,""  ))
```

One could dress it up using `LET`. First, the `SORT(UNIQUE(VSTACK` portions (identical) stack you two lists in a single column for `UNIQUE` to isolate unique items and then `SORT` to sort them as you'd likely like some organization of that... sort... in the result.

There are then two `XLOOKUP`'s that do the same thing as each other, just comparing the combined, uniqui-fied, sorted list to each of your current listings separately, building the two lists of ID's that occur in each source list, and due to the sorting (of identical lists) of their inputs, making them coincidentally align with each other. Their "If Not Found" parameters ensure the blanks in the output where each source list does not have an element found only in the other list.

`HSTACK` then puts the two listings next to each other in a two column output.

And to say it again, using the same interim listing to compare each list to has the nice, but coincidental, effect of those ID's that are identical being listed next to each other.